Linearity when using KeyFrame and Timelime in JavaFX
I have a class with an "animation()" method that makes use of the JavaFX KeyFrame and Timeline classes. When I try to execute this method of object a1 (a1.animation()), the method of object a2 (a2.animation) is also called, and both execute in parallel. What modifications should I make so that the execution of the methods is linear, that is, the method of object a1 executes and at the end, the method of object a2 begins its execution?
I've already tried using the setOnFinished() method, but only the a1 object method is executed, the a2 object method is not executed.
public class Example{

    //method
    public void animation(){
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), event -> {
            /*
             code here
            */
        });

        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }
}

//call method on start

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
        Example a1 = new Example();
        Example a2 = new Example();

        a1.animation();
        a2.animation();
}



I suggest you edit the question provide your attempt at your empty code here block and also describe clearly what it is supposed to do (also in a question edit), so that others can better understand what you are trying to do.  Perhaps an AnimationTimer or a custom Transition might be more appropriate (I don't know), but maybe Timeline with modifications could still be a good fit.

Yes, please [edit] your question to at least add the information you provided in a comment (which has since been deleted along with the associated answer). That information changes things. Ideally, you should be providing a [mre] that truly demonstrates your use case (not just vaguely alludes to it).

Refactor your method so it just returns the animation, instead of playing it:
public class Example{

    //method
    public Animation animation(){
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), event -> {
            /*
             code here
            */
        });

        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        // timeline.play();
        return timeline;
    }
}

This will give you finer control over the playing of the animations. For example, to answer the question asked in the post, you can place both in a SequentialTransition:

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
        Example a1 = new Example();
        Example a2 = new Example();

        SequentialTransition sequential = new SequentialTransition(
            a1.animation(),
            a2.animation()
        );
        sequential.play();
}

More generally, you could use any of the animation API to control each animation and the relationship between them:
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException{
        Example a1 = new Example();
        Example a2 = new Example();

        Animation animation1 = a1.animation();
        Animation animation2 = a2.animation();

        animation1.statusProperty().addListener((_, oldStatus, newStatus) -> {
            // for example:
            if (newStatus == Animation.Status.STOPPED) {
                animation2.play();
            }
        });
        animation1.play();
}


only the code a1.animation() is executed, the code a2.animation() continues without executing because the loop inside the KeyFrame keyFrame object continues infinitely. And you cannot use timeline.stop() to stop the loop because it generates an error:  Cannot stop when embedded in another animation .

@GreatField If the animation continues forever, what do you actually want to happen? You can’t execute the second animation after the first if the first never ends.

exactly, so I would like to stop the first animation from running. I've already tried using the sequential.stop() object within the KeyFrame, but it gives an error because the object has a null value. I've already tried using return; to return void, but the loop continues even when executing return;. I tried other codes but without success

@GreatField Please clarify under which conditions the first animation should finish. Is it a limited number of cycles? Is it user controlled? Is it event-driven? Note if it's a limited number of cycles, why are you using INDEFINITE to begin with?

@Slaw There is an "if else" block inside the KeyFrame loop, which increments the coordinates (x,y) of an object and makes it move in the graphical interface, something like if (coord != coord_MAX){ //set coord. } else{ timeline.stop()}. However, I can't use timeline.stop() when I'm using SequentialTransition.

@GreatField "There is an "if else" block inside the KeyFrame loop". No there isn't. There is no such thing in the KeyFrame you posted in the question (I have no idea what "loop" means here; there is also no loop in the code you posted). Given what you describe, it should still be solvable using this answer; see for example the completely trivial edit I made that will make what you describe work.
